# How to get multiple input from user in one line c++

Tags: c++

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

the first line is how many input will user give.
and the second line is the input from the user. basically it's "c >> a >> b >> c;" but it's up to the user how many input they want.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quite simple. Read an `int` `n` indicating the number of items, then declare a `std::vector<int>` and read in `n` elements in a loop, pushing each onto the vector. This can be done either with an explicit for loop, or using STL functions.

E.g.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;

    std::cin >> n;
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cerr << "Input failed." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<int> nums(n);

    for (auto& x : nums) {
        std::cin >> x;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "Input failed." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This will read `n` values from standard input even across multiple lines, *but* if you want to read those values from the next line, you'd want to read that line into a string, feed that string into a `std::istringstream`, and then extract from that stream.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    int n;

    std::cin >> n;
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cerr << "Input failed." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<int> nums(n);
    std::string line;
    std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream ss { line };

    for (auto& x : nums) {
        ss >> x;
        if (ss.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "Input failed." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to read input and store in `std::vector`. You can resize the vector to hold `n` elements by passing `n` to its constructor. Then you can read into the `std::vector` like you do for a normal array.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
   
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cin >> v[i];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @ZongruZhan, but how to pass `n` to `std::array`? I tried but it threw some error, expecting a `const`, something like that. Maybe you can post another answer with your solution using `std::array`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean C99 style runtime-sized arrays, which is permitted in g++ compiler.

`int v[n];`

Comment: But, it's not standard C++ and not all compilers will support it.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use a `std::vector` over any other data type.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector <int> xs;

  int n;
  std::cin >> n;

  // method 1
  std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator <int> ( std::cin ), n, std::back_inserter( xs ) );

  // method 2
  int x; while (n--) { std::cin >> x; xs.push_back( x ); }
```

In general, your goal should not be to do things “in one line”, but to do things correctly and succinctly, favoring correctness over terseness.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter n ";
    std::cin >> n;

    int inputUser[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cin >> inputUser[i];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << " "<<inputUser[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int inputUser[n];` is no standard C++ and not all compilers support it. The size has to be known at compile-time. Better use `vector`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).